# Foreign Currency bank account

Tags: united-kingdom, banking

What is the best option to open a foreign currency bank account in the UK?
I have cash savings of around 5k USD that I don't plan on using and would like to keep them somewhere safe without paying excessive fees for the account or for depositing/withdrawing them.

Thanks,
Tohiko

Comment: Do you want to also earn interest on the USD savings, or just keep them somewhere safe + without many/any fees?

Comment: I don't need interest. Just the safety without paying the fees.

Comment: Did you check with your current US bank about keeping the account open? That might be easier and/or have lower fees than an international bank account / UK-based USD account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sterling current account with a UK bank you can ask them about their foreign currency accounts

[example](http://www.barclays.co.uk/Otheraccounts/Currencyaccounts/ForeignCurrencyAccount/P1242557963858)

There are likely to be fees (e.g. £7/quarter if quarterly average balance < $2000 USD]. £6 per transfer).